# Logistic regression for abiotic influences on behavior

Tags: regression, logistic

What I am looking to do is test for a correlation between an activity (in this case nesting) with cumulative rainfall from the previous two weeks. For example, say one individual nested on DayX where the total rainfall from the previous 2 weeks is 4cm and another individual nested on DayY with 8cm of prior rain, and there are days where it had rained with no nesting events. An example of the data is such:

```
Day 2wk_rain number_nested number_available
1     2            0              9 
2     2            0              9
3     4            0              9
4     3            1              9
5     6            1              9
6     2            2              9
:     :            :              :
15    8            9              9
```

Analyzing this with cumulative rainfall throughout the period seemed straightforward, but when I decided to look further at a more localized temporal scale it threw me for a loop. My main objective is to find out whether rainfall can trigger nesting behavior within a few days, hence scaling it down.

I still think I need to stick with logistic regression due to the nature of the response variable, but how I go about analyzing it and presenting it in an understandable way seems to elude me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want either A) a survival analysis with time-varying covariates. The dependent variable is then "time to nesting" and the covariate is "amount of rain" or B) a survival analysis where the dependent variable is "rainfall to nesting". Which one would depend on whether time also is of interest (I'm guessing it is, but it's your field). Cox proportional hazards would probably be a good choice of survival models.

I would start, though, with some graphs. If you don't have a great many birds, you could graph each one's behavior. If you do have many (more than, say, about 30) then the standard plots from survival analysis would be good.

What software are you using?

Comment: I plan on using R for this analysis. I have 8 years of data, and on average data for 10 birds/year. Separating by year does matter because of how variable the environment is. Time is part of the question, since obviously the more time a bird has, the higher the chances of it actually nesting are.

Comment: With 10 birds per year, you could do a plot like this:  On the x-axis, you could have cumulative rainfall, then on the y-axis there would be 8 lines (one for each year) and then a mark (a dot or whatever) for each bird's nesting time and each dot could be labeled with number of days. 

Alternatively, use same x-axis and put lines for each year with labels on that axis for days.